# Is there another pair of consecutive primes with this property?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Denote $$r(n)$$ to be the number that occurs if we reverse the digits of $n$

Suppose, $\ (p,q)\ $ is a pair of consecutive primes.

The only prime $p$ with the property $$r(p)=2q$$ I found is $\ p=479\ $.

> Is there another prime $p$ with the given property ?

For the opposite equation, namely $$r(q)=2p$$ I did not find yet a single example.

I checked both equations upto $p=10^9$

Comment: I'm guessing you see the restrictions to even digit starts for p, same digit length for q, 1 mod 6values of p, mapping to 5 mod 6 values of q, and 5 mod 6 vslues of p mapping to 1 mod 6 values for q ?

Comment: is the multiplier on 9 predictable on reversal of a number ? if so we might be able to figure out mod 7. and therefore mod 42.

Comment: The same $10^9$ claim is made at https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php?short=479 and attributed to Galliani.

Comment: Now posted to (but closed on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330066/is-there-a-proof-that-479-is-the-only-prime-with-this-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two pairs of consecutive primes $(p,q)$ with $r(q)=2p$:
$$p=4574\cdot 10^{123} - 3123,\quad q = 4574\cdot 10^{123} - 2581$$
and
$$p=494\cdot 10^{213} - 303,\quad q = 494\cdot 10^{213} - 211.$$

**Background.**
The difference between consecutive primes is much smaller than the primes (e.g., see [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture)), but there are not so many patterns for numbers $(p,q)$ with $r(p)=2q$ or $r(q)=2p$ with small difference $q-p$. Furthermore, some of these patterns produce numbers with small factors, and thus they cannot deliver primes. Below I describe patterns for the differences below $100$ that can potentially produce prime pairs.

The most simple and attractive pattern for $r(q)=2p$ with difference $2$ is $p = 5\cdot 10^n - 3$ and $q = 5\cdot 10^n - 1$ with $n\geq 3$. As soon as these $p$ and $q$ are both prime, we are guaranteed that they are consecutive as prime twins. Unfortunately, if such prime twins exist, $n$ would be very large as can be seen from the sequences [A103003](https://oeis.org/A103003) and [A056712](https://oeis.org/A056712) lacking small common terms.

Next possible prime difference in increasing order are

- $28$ given by $p = 48\cdot 10^n - 41$ and $q = 48\cdot 10^n - 13$ with $r(p)=2q$ for all $n\geq 2$.
- $32$ given by $p=454\cdot 10^n - 323$ and $q= 454\cdot 10^n - 291$ with $r(q)=2p$ for all $n\geq 3$.
- $58$ given by $p = 493\cdot 10^n - 411$ and $q=493\cdot 10^n - 353$ with $r(p)=2q$ for all $n\geq 3$.
- $62$ given by $p=474\cdot 10^n - 313$ and $q=474\cdot 10^n - 251$  with $r(q)=2p$ for all $n\geq 3$.
- $92$ given by $p = 494\cdot 10^n - 303$ and $q = 494\cdot 10^n - 211$ with $r(q)=2p$ for all $n\geq 3$.

I've quickly tested these patterns for $n\leq 1000$ and for the last one found the second pair of consecutive primes given at the top.

**UPDATE.** I've also made a more extensive search over larger differences and found another pair (coming first at the top) having difference 542.

Comment: Good job! (+1) But you did not find a solution with $r(p)=2q$ , right ?

Comment: @Peter: No. I've found only nearly consecutive pairs like $(4989999999999999999799, 4989999999999999999947)$ with one other prime in between.

Comment: $$p=4776*10^{2979}-8441$$ solves the original problem. Thank you Max, I used your idea to find it !

Comment: @Peter: Good catch! I did not bother looking at exponents greater than 1000.